# How to close a stream event when I don't have the channel?

Tags: stream

I opened a stream to listen to events. The server rebooted. How do I close the stream when I don't have the channel object? Will Horizon stop calling in when the client does not respond? Is there a way to tell Horizon to drop all streams to a specific URL?

Comment: How did you open the stream? Using an SDK?

Comment: Yes. Java SDK and JS SDK.